# Addon gets uninstalled when there is an upgrade process

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I was wondering what is the proper way to test if reason == ADDON_UPGRADE works for bootstraped addons? Here is the way I'm testing it: I have two versions 2.1 and 2.2. So I manually install the 2.1 version and then without uninstalling 2.1 I install 2.2, startup function in bootstrap.js recognizes this as an ADDON_UPGRADE, however it fires ADDON_UNINSTALL and removes all my preference objects. In [Mozilla website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions), they say that the "uninstall function fires on downgrade and upgrade as well so you should make sure it is an uninstall by doing this:"

```
function uninstall(aData, aReason) {
     if (aReason == ADDON_UNINSTALL) {
          //clear prefrence objects
          console.log('really uninstalling');
     } else {
          console.log('not a permanent uninstall, likely an upgrade or downgrade');
     }
}
```

I do this, but still after doing my own testing method, all the preference objects get cleared. Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The ADDON_UNINSTALL would be of the previous verison, of version 2.1, then ADDON_UPGRADE will fire in startup for 2.2. If you use this method and only clear preferences in the ADD_UNINSTALL part of uninstall it should work as expected. Btw excellent of you to clean up on uninstalls :)